# How to get tomorrow date as a string and date format in android for using in sqlite query?

Tags: java, android, sqlite, android-sqlite

I am trying to delete some records in s table where date is today's date and tomorrow's date

```
public void deleteAll()
{
    // SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    // db.delete(TABLE_NAME,null,null);
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();

    // db.execSQL("delete  from "+ TABLE_NAME);
    // db.execSQL("TRUNCATE table" + TABLE_NAME);
    Date c = Calendar.getInstance().getTime(); System.out.println("Current time => " + c);
    SimpleDateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");
    String current_Date = df.format(c);

    Log.e("Current_Date=", current_Date);

    db.execSQL("DELETE FROM SchedledMeetings WHERE Meeting_Date = '''+current_Date+''' ");
    db.close();
}
```

but would like to get these as a string and date format using a Sqlite query.

Comment: all meetings are getting deleted

Comment: Please update your answer by [edit]ing it, instead of using comments.

Comment: Also, your code can be SQL injected.

Answer (score 2):

First I must say that it is wrong to store dates in `SQLite` in format `"dd/MM/yyyy"` because this is not a comparable format so it cannot be easily used to make selections when you want to get rows between dates. Also date functions of `SQLite` would not recognize this format so you would have each time to convert it.  
Better use this format: `"yyyy-MM-dd"`. 
  
Use this code:

```
Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();

Date c = calendar.getTime();
SimpleDateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");

String current_Date = df.format(c);

calendar.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_YEAR, 1);
c = calendar.getTime();
String tomorrow_Date = df.format(c);

db.execSQL("DELETE FROM SchedledMeetings WHERE (Meeting_Date='" + current_Date + "') OR (Meeting_Date='" + tomorrow_Date + "')");
db.close();
```

Notice that your `DELETE` statement should look like this:

```
db.execSQL("DELETE FROM SchedledMeetings WHERE (Meeting_Date='" + current_Date + "') OR (Meeting_Date='" + tomorrow_Date + "')");
```

this way you pass the values of `current_Date` and `tomorrow_Date` and not the strings `"current_Date"` and `"tomorrow_Date"`.  
This will delete all rows containing current date and tomorrow's date.

Comment: actually can i contact u personally can u mail me

Comment: Sorry, but I don't do personal contacts out of the SO scope.